# Is this legal/safe C++? (downcasting into same-size inheriting class)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Sorry for the non-descript title, but I'm having a hard way with words right now. I'll just jump into it:

```
class A
{
public:

protected:
    int doSomething();
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int doSomething() { return A::doSomething(); }
};

...

A *a = new A;
B *b = static_cast<B*>(a);

cout << b->doSomething();
```

Notably, B inherits A and does not add any data members or virtual functions, and does not override any virtual functions. This means an instance of B should be equivalent in memory to an instance of A, I assume.

Basically, is this safe? I'm pretty sure it's not legal, but is it portable? Are there any potential consequences of relying on something like this? (Other than the normal yadayada.)

Obviously this is bad practice, but I see it much like I see casting away const - it's something that may be better than an alternative (if there is one.) However, if you have any non-obvious reasons it may be bad, I'm definitely interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if nothing obviously bad will happen, the question is, why would you be forced to do something like this?

If you only want a wrapper, it is much cleaner design to make A a member of B, and let B forward the calls to A.

Comment: it depends by the design. maybe one would want B to be the same type as A (use an instance of B wherever A is espected). Also B may be expanded in a later time.

Comment: edit: Actually, now that I reread your answer, I see what you mean. This is definitely a valid point.

Answer (score 2):

This code isn't bad but it dosn't buy you anything.  You could do the same thing but provide the flexibly of composition by doing something like this.

```
class A
{
public:

protected:
    int doSomething();
};

template <class T> 
class B : public T
{
 ... 
}
```

Then in your client code you can compose an object that offer feature sets.  With the inclusiveness of vardic templates you can build objects by compision from the consumer point of view.

```
B<A> Ob;
```

Also Take a look at [CRTP](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern&ei=tfcrT-S1Cs_lggevxIjLDw&usg=AFQjCNEHg13YDzVZYJvQCGQFQOBOxE5PvQ&sig2=FbhHzKxSrTIVQmNcEiiIqA) pattern.

Comment: This is an excellent point. However, I'm electing to give the answer to @kotlinski, because their answer is closer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pretty sure it's not legal, but is it portable?

The only way to be portable is to be legal. Unless by "portable" you mean porting between a small set of similar systems.

Comment: Indeed, I mean a small set of similar systems. That describes the majority existing implementations of C++.

Of course, I know you're trying to be technical, but let's be reasonable. Just because someone _could_ break this doesn't mean they will or that it'd be a good idea to.

Comment: @John - I'm sure it *will* break some day. You call a function from class B without ever creating an object of class B. The compiler optimizer could very well figure that out and remove the function.

Comment: @BoPersson No it can't. I'm holding a pointer of it, casting something to it, and using it. Optimizing out that function would cause a linker error. The function would have to be optimized out at linking time anyway, so it'd make absolutely no sense to use the fact that the class was never 'new'd to optimize out a member function - instead, just look at references to the function.

But that's a moot point anyway as the actual trick would still work. All you'd have to do is tell your (broken) compiler to not optimize it by doing something that prevents it from doing so.